# Hasse Principle Violation example on Birch Swinnerton-Dyer-Dyer paper

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have come across the following surface as an example of a violation to the Hasse Principle.

**(1)** $uv = x^2 - 13y^2$
**(2)** $(u+v)(u+2v)= x^2 - 13z^2$

I am trying to show it has solutions in all fields of p-adic numbers and I can't see what is wrong with the following method:

$x^2 - 13z^2 = (u+v)(u+2v) = u^2 + 3uv +2v^2$.

So we have that

**(3)** $x^2 - 13z^2 = u^2 +3uv +2v^2$

By **(1)**

$3uv = 3x^2 - 39y^2$

Hence plugging this in to **(3)**

$x^2 - 13z^2 = u^2 + 3x^2 - 39y^2 + 2v^2$

So we have

**(4)** $39y^2 - 13z^2 = u^2 +2x^2 +2v^2$

So the surface defined by **(1),(2)** has solutions if and only if **(4)** does. 
However **(4)** has solution $u=10, v=1, x=1, y=2, z=2$. Which isn't a solution to **(1),(2)**.

Comment: $(4)$ is a *consequence* of $(1)$ and $(2)$, but it does not imply them.

Comment: So in essence all I have shown is that satisfying (4) is a sufficient but not necessary condition for a solution to be valid for (1),(2)?

Comment: You've shown that satisfying (4) is necessary, but not sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write that
"So the surface defined by (1),(2) has solutions if and only if (4) does."
but you've only used equation (1) to simplify (2) to (4), so it looks like you've only shown
"So the surface defined by (1),(2) has solutions if and only if (1),(4) does.".
You can't forget about equation (1) just because you plugged it in, it still has to be satisfied by any solution.

As you can see your solution does not satisfy (1).